# Classical Mechanics, The Theoretical Minimum: error in answer to partial derivatives exercise?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation

I'm reading Leonard Susskind's Classical Mechanics, The Theoretical Minimum, and I'm on the interlude on partial derivatives. There is an exercise that asks you to find all of the first and second order partial derivatives of the following function,

$V(x,y) = (x/y) e^{x^2+y^2}$

I've successfully found the first derivative w.r.t. x,

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} V(x,y) =  \frac{e^{x^2+y^2}}{y}(1+2x^2)$

But my answer for the second derivative doesn't match the answers given [here](http://www.madscitech.org/tm/slns/i3e1.pdf),

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x} V(x,y) = \frac{e^{x^2+y^2}}{y}(2x)(2x^2 + 3)$

A quick [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%28x%5E%282%29%2By%5E%282%29%29%2Fy%29*%281%2B2x%5E%282%29%29) search seems to agree with my answer, is this correct?

Comment: Wolfram alpha is rarely wrong so trust it!

Comment: Why -1? This is a mathematics question, but from a physics book. I wanted help on a question. There are no other sources of help specific to this question online. I turned to SE for clarification. I really don't see how that deserves a vote down

Comment: First off this is an obvious **maths** question from  a physics book,which gives an introduction of **maths** required to understand the physics presented in the book. Furthermore see [Should any check my work questions be made on topic?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) post on meta for more information.

Comment: On a side note: It is usually discouraged to ask yes/no questions because the answers yes/no are too short to write as an answer!

Comment: Fair enough. This is probably more suitable for the maths site, but I won't cross post. If this kind of question isn't suitable for SE though then where is? It's does seem a bit silly to have a solitary 'yes' answer, but equally if I was wrong it would have been an opportunity for someone to explain the correct answer

Comment: There is probably an error in Prof Susskind's Book, everyone makes mistakes and they are more visible in the written form. I've also checked it with wxMaxima and the result I have is $\frac{\left( 4\,{x}^{3}+6\,x\right) \,{e}^{{y}^{2}+{x}^{2}}}{y}$. It is usually better to trust computers for *utterly* mechanical computations than humans.

Comment: Well maybe you could ask them to reply either a yes or a no including an explanation of why the answer was correct or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct.
Solution in the pdf is correct until last step (also in the middle when he splits partial derivative of $(2x^2+1) e^a /y$ but magically corrects in next step) .
In the last step he applies chain rule incorrectly.

Chain rule applied while calculating first derivative is also incorrect but answer is correct (idk how).

Overall not a good book/source to start learning. (I feel).